# ContiguousArray to UnsafePointer conversion cannot be done

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am trying to call cblas functions from a user defined Matrix type, which uses an array to hold matrix elements.  A very simplified form of the code is here:

```
struct BoxArr{
    var y: Array<Double>
    init( y: Array<Double> ){
        self.y = y
    }
}

var a = BoxArr( y: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] )
let s = cblas_dasum( Int32(a.y.count), a.y, 1 )
print(s)
```

The above code works with no problem, producing the correct sum of 6.0.  Note that the function cblas_dasum receives three arguments, which are (1) the number of elements in the array, (2) the pointer to the array holding the numbers, and (3) stride.  I am having a type conversion problem with the second argument.  If I change the type of the struct member y from Array to ContiguousArray as I did in the following:

```
struct BoxContArr{
    var y: ContiguousArray<Double>
    init( y: ContiguousArray<Double> ){
        self.y = y
    }
}

var a = BoxContArr( y: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] )
let s = cblas_dasum( Int32(a.y.count), a.y, 1 )
print(s)
```

I receive the following error:

**`Cannot convert value of type 'ContiguousArray<Double>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Double>?'`**

In the former case, the second argument `a.y`'s type `Array<Double>` was implicitly converted to `UnsafePointer<Double>` but in the latter case `ContiguousArray<Double>` was not converted to `UnsafePointer<Double>`.  I wonder why this is happening and how to fix it. I prefer using ContiguousArray for possibly better performance. I made shallow copies of the arrays in the constructor but this is not changing the outcome (In the extended implementation, a deep copy is done.)

Comment: Are we talking about `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`?

Comment: you could probably change the second parameter of the function cblas_dasum to the type ContiguousArray<Double>

Comment: @matt  I did try withUnsafePointer and withUnsafeMutablePointer and placed the cblas_dasum() call wihtin the closure but I had the same problem.

Comment: @Mamaessen: the function cblas_dasum is defined in Accelerate frameword and it expects an UnsafePointer<Double> as its second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer needs to be to the first element of the buffer:

```
    var a = BoxContArr( y: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] )
    a.y.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
        let s = cblas_dasum( Int32(a.y.count), ptr.baseAddress, 1 )
        print(s) // 6.0
    }
```

Comment: I tried your answer and the execution does not get completed.  This is what I see:  Simultaneous accesses to 0x100005148, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at simple_speedy_array1`main + 199 (0x100000d57).
Current access (a read) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00007fff6af0a170 swift_beginAccess + 568
1    simple_speedy_array1               0x0000000100000f70 closure #1 in  + 73
...
Program ended with exit code: 9

Comment: I am using Swift 5.0.  Swift 4.2 were okay some of calls similar to the ones that I posted in the question but 5.0 is not.

Comment: Calling cblas_dasum() inside a structure method is a better choice: let s = cblas_dasum( Int32(y.count), y, 1 ); but this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid the simultaneous access would get you! That's the problem with your struct.

Comment: OK fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: BoxArr needs to be replace with BoxContArr.  Thank you.

Comment: Right, I'll fix that just in case anyone else ever sees this.